# Can I use an HTML form's action property to move between React Routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a React app, and getting some trouble with React Router.
First of all, my url always has some weird hashstring at its' end.
For example: 
   http://localhost:3000/#/?_k=gb3epe

Also, I'm not sure whether the hashtag in the url and the following gibberish are part of the same problem or if they're related to 2 different problems. (I'm currently using React-Router v1.0).

Secondly, I think that the weird URL is preventing me from using the "action" property on forms, and would also like to know if there is a better way to move around React renders then relaying on forms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about react-router `v1.0`, then to remove this hash string you should pass a `{ queryKey: false }` parameter to the createBrowserHistory  function.

```
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={ createBrowserHistory({ queryKey: false }) } 
          routes={ ReactRoutes } />, 
  document.getElementById('some-container')
);
```

To move between routes `react-router` provides `Link` component which you can use inside your components.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out.

Also, does the hashtag issue appear in React-Router v2.0 as well? 
And is there a different way of addressing it?

Comment: @DougieHauser In `v2.0` you will have `hashHistory` and `browserHistory` separately. So just by using `browserHistory` (which is recommended) you will not have these hash strings by default.